# MySQLdb not INSERTING, _mysql does fine

Tags: python, mysql

Okay, I log onto the MySQL command-line client as root. I then open or otherwise run a python app using the MySQLdb module as root. When I check the results using python (IDLE), everything looks fine. When I use the MySQL command-line client, no INSERT has occurred. If I change things around to _mysql instead of MySQLdb, everything works fine. I'd appreciate any clarification(s).

"Works" until IDLE/Virtual machine is reset:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='*******',db='test')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES ('somevalue');""",)
```

Works:

```
import _mysql
db = _mysql.connect(user='root', passwd='*******',db='test')
db.query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('somevalue');")
```

System info:
Intel x86
WinXP
Python 2.5
MySQL 5.1.41
MySQL-Python 1.2.2

Answer (score 17):

You can use `db.commit()` to submit data or set `db.autocommit()` after `_mysql.connect(...)` to autocommit requests.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for posting it (almost 3 years ago)!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Funnily enough most tutorials do *not* mention this which surprises me.

Answer (score 4):

I think they use different autocommit settings. Use commit() after inserting data.